# Is there way in Karate to conevert Json to csv

Tags: karate

I am running db query and getting below output in Json format.Is there way to convert the below json output in .csv file (csv format)  in karate or do we need write our java utility to do this

if karate has inbuilt feature to convert json to csv file let me know

```
{
 "recordset": [
{ 
"Key1": "Value1",
"Key2": "Value2",
}

{
"Key1": "Value1",
"Key2": "Value2",
}
]
}

Thanks In advance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is coming in 0.9.6 final. Expect an RC4 next week.

https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#karate-tocsv

Try and build locally if you can: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide